# Application.properties in static method

Tags: java, spring, properties, components

I am having trouble getting application.properties in a static method.
I am using `log4j`. It requires a class with a static method to create the `dB connection`.

I create this method but I need the properties for the current profile. All I get is null when using `@value`.
How do I make this work?

Comment: If you can, please update your question, adding more details such as the code you wrote and how you're trying to use it. More people will be able to help you out that way.

Comment: If you can’t understand the question without a code example,it’s unlikely you are going to be able to help...